# Want to Display Big image on thumbnail click in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    ASP Code is!
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="newappexample._Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Photo Gallery</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            .black_overlay{
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0%;
                left: 0%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: black;
                z-index:1001;
                -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            }
            .white_content {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                top: 25%;
                left: 25%;
                width: 50%;
                height: 50%;
                padding: 16px;
                border: 16px solid orange;
                background-color: white;
                z-index:1002;
                overflow: auto;
            }
                    div.center
            {
                margin-left: 20%;
                margin-right: 20%;
                width: 770px;
                background-color:#FFF;
            }
            div.middle
            {
                background-image:url('images/center.jpg');
                background-repeat: repeat-y;
                min-height:200px;
                margin-left: 100px;
                margin-right: 100px;
                margin-top:0px;
                padding-top:0px;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="panelIDtb" BorderColor="Red" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="GrayText" BorderWidth="1px" Width="1000px" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server" Height="130px">
        <asp:Repeater
            id="RepeaterImage"
            runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton id="Image1" Width="100px" Height="100px" OnClientClick="" OnClick="ImageButOnClick"
                    ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' Runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Panel>
        <div class="middle">
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelBigImage" BorderStyle="Dotted" BackColor="AntiqueWhite" BorderWidth="2px" runat="server" Width="800px" Height="700px">

        </asp:Panel>
        </div>
        </div>
             </form>
    </body>
    </html>


and My C Sharp code behind is!

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace newappexample
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        void Page_Load()
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                RepeaterImage.DataSource = GetPhotos();
                RepeaterImage.DataBind();
            }
        }

        public List<String> GetPhotos()
        {
            List<string> photos = new List<string>();
            string photoPath = MapPath("~/myimages/images_tn");
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(photoPath);
            foreach (string photo in files)
                photos.Add("~/myimages/images_tn/" + Path.GetFileName(photo));
            return photos;
        }
        public void ImageButOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // var newP = "Changing Some Paragraph";
           // PanelBigImage.Visible = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Thumbnail Images are displaying. As i click on thumbnail i want to preview big image related to that thumbnail. How can i do this?? This task is new for me and i am also a beginner. I googled a lot but i didnt reached to a decision and previously i didnt use any JQuery or javascript like.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) with jquery. Easy to configure and use and brings some bonus effects too.

How to include lightbox in your project and page is documented on the site of lightbox.

Update your panel markup as shown below:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelIDtb" BorderColor="Red" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="GrayText" BorderWidth="1px" Width="1000px" ScrollBars="Auto" runat="server" Height="130px">
   <asp:Repeater id="RepeaterImage" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <div>
            <a href="<%# Container.DataItem %>" rel="lightbox[imgs]"><img src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' /></a>
         </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I downloaded the light-box and see the sample. but how i deploy that light box on c sharp and ASP page. I didnt do that before. Please can you tell me little about that, I will be very thankful to you. :)

Comment: Is there any need to import or copy downloaded light-box to .net folder?

Comment: It is general very useful to include downloaded material like this into your project.